# Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter : Ionic

Tags: angular, http-headers, ionic3, mean-stack

This is my code

```
gettheLinkedinUserDetails(token: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Authorization','Bearer '+token);
    this.http.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url)?format=json',{headers: headers})
    .subscribe(profileData => {
      alert(profileData + 'hii');
    })
  }
```

I'm using using `HttpClientModule` & I'm getting the error as

`Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.`
how can I solve this issue?

Comment: could you try changing the headers property type to any ;

Comment: No but I got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpHeaders` instead of `Headers` from `@angular/common/http`.

```
gettheLinkedinUserDetails(token: string) {

  let headers: new HttpHeaders(
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        { 'Authorization','Bearer ' + token });
          this.http.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url)?format=json',
          {headers: headers})
            .subscribe(profileData => {
                alert(profileData + 'hii');
          });
      }
```